# How far can we take tool fabrication questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

Another discussion of scope for questions. Something like wooden tool handles is in scope I would figure as it is just a matter of turning, carving or cutting wood.

What about the metal components of tools? I am looking to make a froe. I will need to source materials. Since it is a *mostly* straight flat piece of metal there is not much going on. Need to know what I could do to make the initial edge... like an angle grinder. I don't have access to any smithing tools really So i don't know what my options are for attaching it to he handle. I could just put some bolts through the blade and the handle but that seems only to have limited viability.

This is very much for the blacksmithing SE that is starting up but it is still a wood working tool. Please don't answer about the froe. It was an example of something I would like to ask. Just want to know how far we can take this.

Plenty of woodworkers make their own tools so do we only allow one that are strictly about the wood themselves?

Comment: This is a great question and I've been debating starting a similar question about finishing options.

Comment: @Graphus Inspiration for that would be because of the bronzing question I assume?

Comment: Yep, the very one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a general question about attaching non-wooded things to a piece of wood as part of a woodworking project is on-topic here.

I think making an initial edge on a blade is close enough to sharpening a blade and could be on-topic.  Maybe it's the same technique that you'd use if your blade becomes too dull to sharpen (which would certainly be on-topic).

However, if you're trying to build a lathe from scratch and want to know what type of wires to use in your motor, we would probably flag that as off-topic.

So the distinction of whether a tool-building question is on-topic is probably gradual, but certainly at some point, it becomes off-topic.

Comment: What about metal selection for the fore blade

Comment: @Matt Seems on-topic. It's like asking to use carbide vs cobalt drill bits.

Comment: Thanks. Just getting ready to go on a question spree again.